# Jmeter: How to pass json value as in array in Http request

Tags: jmeter

[image: Response from previous request]

[image: Post body using a previous response and pass it as array]

[API Request body[[image: ][1][1]]I am new to jmeter. I have one HTTP Request which fetches the data and response is like below:

[
    "{\"senderId\":\"3\",\"receiverId\":\"90\",\"type\":\"1\",\"objectId\":\"1\",\"notificationDetails\":null}",
    "{\"senderId\":\"3\",\"receiverId\":\"90\",\"type\":\"3\",\"objectId\":\"1\",\"notificationDetails\":null}",
    "{\"senderId\":\"3\",\"receiverId\":\"90\",\"type\":\"2\",\"objectId\":\"1\",\"notificationDetails\":null}",
    "{\"senderId\":\"3\",\"receiverId\":\"90\",\"type\":\"0\",\"objectId\":\"1\",\"notificationDetails\":null}"
]

I want to pass this json to Next Http request as an array
my request is like below:

/move/seen/?notifications[]="{\"senderId\":\"3\",\"receiverId\":\"90\",\"type\":\"1\",\"objectId\":\"1\",\"notificationDetails\":null}",
    "{\"senderId\":\"3\",\"receiverId\":\"90\",\"type\":\"3\",\"objectId\":\"1\",\"notificationDetails\":null}",
    "{\"senderId\":\"3\",\"receiverId\":\"90\",\"type\":\"2\",\"objectId\":\"1\",\"notificationDetails\":null}",
    "{\"senderId\":\"3\",\"receiverId\":\"90\",\"type\":\"0\",\"objectId\":\"1\",\"notificationDetails\":null}"&userId=90

Can someone please guide me how to do this in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is  full response, if you really want to fetch full response then use JSR223 Post Processor as shown below:-

[image]

[image]

Fetch it using ${response}

But it is hardly the case and should be avoided. So, for fetching specific data use post processors:-

JSON Extractor for JSON

CSS/JQuery Extractor for HTML extraction

XPath Extractor for XML

Regular Expression Extractor for any text

Refer below link for more on JSON:-
https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/easy-scripting-of-json-applications-with-apache-jmeter/

Hope this helps.

**Update:-**
Use "Body Data" to send the parameter.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the valuable response, When I use the response of the previous request and pass it as array, I check the request body and it seems like its not the same response which I am trying to use from the previous request. Please see attached images in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help